# Java Inheritance strange behaviour

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

The following code prints output as 40 instead of 30. I'm not able to figure out the solution. Please help with the code.

```
class Base {

  int value = 0;

    Base() {
      addValue();
    }

    void addValue() {
      value += 10;
    }

    int getValue() {
      return value;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

  Derived() {
    addValue();
  }

  void addValue() {
    value +=  20;
  }
}

public class Test{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Derived();
    System.out.println(b.getValue());
  }
}
```

The implicit super reference in `Derived` constructor calls `Base` constructor which in turn calls method `addValue()` in the class `Base` results in value variable as 10 and then `addValue()` in the `Derived` class should add 20 to value 10. 
So the final output is 30.

But the code prints 40.

Comment: (I understand this is different in C++, which doesn't follow overrides of more derived class from the constructor as the more derived class wont have been initialised.)

Comment: Please, choose an answer to your question so others can find it easily.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Comment: @TomHawtin are you saying this same code in C++ will output 30?  In that case, I can definitely see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @BrandonG Yup. (Just tried it out and added it as an answer.)

Answer (score 8):

The `addValue` method is overridden in the `Derived` class. When a method is overridden, calling a method on an instance of this class always calls the overridden version, even when the call happens in the base class.

Comment: yes, but method call is done in the constructor which starts executing at the object creation new Derived() and calls Derived class constructor which again calls Base class constructor because of implicit super() reference and thus Base class addValue() executes first followed by addValue() in Derived class.

Comment: No, this is not how it works. A Derived object is a Derived object from the very beginning, and all method calls will call the implementations in the Derived class, even if the call happens before the Derived constructor has executed.

Answer (score 4):

In class `Derived`, the method `void addValue()` points to the method defined in Derived, not in `Base`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably when you extend the Base class

```
class Derived extends Base {

  Derived() {

    addValue();

  }

  void addValue() { //here

    value +=  20;

  }

}
```

you put the method name same in the `Base Class` and this overrides the default one which is:

```
   void addValue() {
      value += 10;
    }
```

So, the output is **40 -> 20 + 20**

Answer (score 1):

As others have got there before me: `addValue` is overridden in `Derived`, as it is an accessible method with the same name and same parameter types. Typically you would add the `@Override` annotation to the override method. The method in the derived class even though the base class is still under construction.

Not all languages do the same thing. C++, for example, will not run overridden methods from derived class whilst the base constructor is still running. The equivalent program in C++ does show 30.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int value;

    Base() : value(0) {
      addValue();
    }

    virtual void addValue() {
      value += 10;
    }

    int getValue() {
      return value;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() {
    addValue();
  }

  virtual void addValue() {
    value +=  20;
  }
};

int main() {
    Base *b = new Derived();
    std::cout << b->getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`addValue()` is override in `Derived` class and you created a `Derived` class object. So whenever the `addValue()` called by this instance. Always methos is called of `Derived` class. So thats why `addValue()` of Derived class called twice. Once in the `Base` class constructor and second in `Derived` class constructor.

Comment: But Derived class constructor will implicitly point to parent class constructor using super() reference and Base class constructor starts executing which should call addValue() in the Base class

Comment: Yes. When in the base class addValue() called it executes the derived class function because it has the reference of derived class. If function is not overidden in the Derived class then the base class function is called.

Comment: If you put the add value code in both constructors like in base constructor write code value+=10 and in derived constructor write value+=20. Then your final value will be 30.

Answer (score 0):

As others discussed earlier Method Overriding property applies to method call in the base class well.

By this java applies Run Time Polymorphism *i.e., Based on the object that is invoked at run time, the method which is to be executed is decided.*
For e.g.,

- If super class object is used to invoke the method, then super class
  method will be executed.
- If sub class object is used to invoke the
  method, then sub class method will be executed.

If we don't want to override, we can make the parent method as `private` instead of default *private package*. Now we will be getting 30 as output. *As the method which cannot be inherited then it cannot be overridden*

```
class Base {

    int value = 0;

    Base() {
        addValue();
    }

    private void addValue() {
        value += 10;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    Derived() {
        addValue();
    }

    void addValue() {
        value +=  20;
    }
}

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Derived();
        System.out.println(b.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now, the output is **30**.